# C++ on bare board Embedded System

Tags: c++, arm, rtos

I am trying to port a library which is written in C++ on our Embedded System. The embedded system is written in C programming language on ARM platform. I have been thinking it is possible that I could do that. C++ programming language is much more complicated than C.

Does C++ library require the environment to run properly? If I do that, the problems I might encounter.

1. C++'s OOP model requires special memory management system.[new, delete, smart pointers]
2. C++'s exception handling, it seems to me that is is a kind of myth. As far as I know, WinCE's C++ exception handling requires support from ARM-core/Kernel.
3. Other features, such as Run-time type information

Could you please share some experience with me. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: Do you need to have this lib in C? Or do you just have to compile it and provide a C API to communicate with?

Comment: What does your compiler say?

Comment: Right, you can "communicate" with it, but how? the library has to run somewhere in your system, right? For instance, in an RTOS, can we add this library in a task to communicate with?

Comment: We have not got this library yet, but they are asking for the possibility and we are studying this. Frankly, I do not think C compiler/linker will have too much trouble provided if they provide the correct/exported interface [to avoid C++ name mangle]. My concern is that the problem comes during run-time.

Answer (score 1):

Lots depends on your library but on embedded platforms you normally turn off rtti and exception handling. C++ normally requires a memory allocator and is normally implemented in terms of malloc. If it is something else you will havevto provide a default overator new and operator delete implementation. Compiler will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it's unclear if you try to port (i.e. rewrite C++ program to C one) or to just Run C++ program in an embedded environment, and therefore (almost) don't change it. In case of #1 you just should use your mind. No any troubles there (except it make take very long time... ) In case of #2 it won't be easy as well. things to think about (I will assume you use gnu toolchain or derived from it, if no - I am just not aware how things are there)

- do you have a loader which can do this ? That is template symbols should be handled in a special way (they are weak), but it wil bother you only if you use some dylds (dynamic libraries). Your loader should be able to call global constructors and destructors. loading of exception unwinding information is also should be handled by it. A point to take a look is: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_3.0.0/LSB-PDA/LSB-PDA/ehframechpt.html
- You need C++ runtime. I.e. base support for the language, just as a starting point I suggest to take a look here: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++ 
  Taking this also implies working malloc/free function, something similar to mmap.
- if your program uses threads, TLS (thread local storage, thread_local c++ keyword), file processing and exceptions the complexity drastically increases... and I'd want to wish you good luck with porting or using of full version of stdlibc++ (g++) or libc++ (clang)
- just a thing to think is that you need either glibc or some its micro substitutions like https://www.uclibc.org/ In case you use some not standard substitution it's worth to think how you will join it with c++ libraries above (stdlibc++ or libc++, or something else what you in theory may use)

Pondering about such things above I decided that for my own small bare-metal arm project, c++ is too much, and Force is in C.